# Delete sql rows with fk in another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys

I have an example uni database where I am required to update department for the new year. I have the following tables

Table 1 (Department) has the following columns:

```
ID   | NAME | SCHOOL | ACTIVE | SNAPSHOT
860  | SOF  |  20    |   1    | NULL
861  | CS   |  20    |   1    | NULL
```

**ID is PK, int, NOT NULL**

Table 2 (User) has the following columns:

```
ID   | EMPNO | FORENAME | SURNAME | DEPT
1495 | e3456 | Parker   | Sal     |  860
```

**Dept is a FK**

Problem:

The two departments in Table 1 should be updated to a single department as below:

```
ID   | NAME                | SCHOOL | ACTIVE | SNAPSHOT
860  | School of Sciences  |  20    |   1    | NULL
```

I am using the following sql command :

```
DELETE FROM Department WHERE ID = 861
```

And receiving the following error:

> *Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 10
>   The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK__User__Dept". The conflict occurred in database "uniDB", table "dbo.User", column 'Dept'.*

Using the same command I am unable to delete the Dept ID 861 from table 2 (User) since a third table has FK constraint User and therefore, I get the same error as above.

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Your requirements are saying: update name of dept 860 and probably remove dept 861 (as it's stated in `should be updated to a single department as below` paragraph). So, why are you trying to delete dept 860? What's the original task?

Comment: Aside:  You should figure out your datatypes and be consistent. Is `Id` an `Int`? If so, why would you compare it to a string, e,g. `'860'`, and force the database to do a type conversion? (Ref: [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql).)

Comment: Alright, if you've cleared up that 861 must be deleted, then what must happen to user linked to it when it will cease to exist? That's what the error message is saying: _there are user linked to this dept_. Should they be deleted too? Or they must be linked to some other dept after 861 is removed?

Comment: Updated the question. Sorry it was dept 861 that needed to be removed. The task is basically updating the existing two departments to a single department with a changed name. Also, yes ID is an int in the departments table and is referenced in the User table under Dept column. @HABO

Comment: @IvanStarostin Nope just need to change the department and reference the new ID under Dept in the User table. So if 861 is removed they should be refererencing 860 i.e the new dept "School of Sciences".

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what is `nope` related to. `Nope`, you don't need to delete 861? `Nope`, linked to 861 users should not be deleted?

Comment: @IvanStarostin nope is related to users linked to 861 users should not be deleted. Only the dept with ID 861 should be replaced in the user's table with the updated department with ID 860.

Comment: Would it be easier to remove both departments and their IDs and create a completely new ID for the new department. This would then be referenced in the User table since users can be added manually via the web application. @IvanStarostin

Comment: @Maya You seem to have misunderstood my comment. `'7'` and `'seven'` are strings because they are contained in quotation marks. `7` is an integer. If you give SQL Server a comparison like `where Id = '42'` (when `Id` is an `int`) it will dutifully check the data type precedence rules and convert `'42'` to an `int`, and then perform the comparison. In this case it will work, but it is confusing to the reader and will not always do what you might expect.

Comment: @HABO yes it wasn't meant to be '861' but rather 861. It was my typing error and you are absolutely right that iquotations are used for strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change links, then delete:

```
UPDATE u SET
  Dept = 860
FROM User u
WHERE u.Dept = 861

DELETE d
FROM Department d
WHERE d.ID = 861
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked finally. Sorry, I would upvote but can't due to low points.